# sequelize returns empty array at querying

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, pgadmin

doesn't matter if I try `findOne() or findAll()`
I get : []
empty array.

the query being called for `findAll()` is:

`SELECT "id", "password", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "phone", "roleId", "userId", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "Users";`

while when I manually use in pgadmin cli this query:  `select * from Users;`

I get all the rows of the table.

could you please advise?

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../db/database')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//console.log(sequelize);

const User = sequelize.define("Users", {
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                len: [8,40],
                trim: true
            }
        },
        firstName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                len: [0,20],
                trim: true,
                lowercase: true
            }
        },
        lastName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                len: [0,20],
                trim: true,
                lowercase: true
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                len: [0,20],
                trim: true,
                lowercase: true,
                isEmail: true
            }
        },
        phone: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            validate:{
                len: [10,10],
                trim: true,
            }
        },
        roleId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate:{
                trim: true
                /* must convert roleId from string to integer
                toInt(value){
                    return parseInt(value);
               }*/
            }
        },
        userId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    { 
        timestamps: true, 
        versionKey: false,
        hooks:{
            beforeSave: async function(user,options){
                if (user.isModified('password')) {
                    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

User.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    const user = this;
    const userObject = user.toObject();

    delete userObject.password;
    delete userObject.tokens;

    return userObject;
};

User.prototype.generateAuthToken = async function () {
    const user = this;
    const payload = { user };
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 360000
    });
    return token;
};

const findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
   
    const users= await User.findAll();
    const user = await User.findOne({where: {email}});
    if (!user) {
        throw Error('invalid email');
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
        throw Error('invalid password');
    }

    return user;
}

User.sync();

module.exports = {
    User,
    findByCredentials
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT "id", "password", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "phone", "roleId", "userId", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "Users";` from pgAdmin or CLI?

Comment: returns an empty table with the headers mentioned